# Filters items the type with computed property and display in their respected tab

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have data file through which I want get the only items which matches the particular type with condition rendering

//data

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
data: () => ({
 active: 0,
 listData:{
   "A" : [
     {
      "text":"Lorem iPsum",
       "type" : "a1",
     },
     {
      "text":"Ipsum Lorem iPsum",
      "type" : "a1",
     },
     {
       "text":"Lorem",
       "type" : "a1",
   },
      {
       "text":"B1 text i.",
       "type" : "b1",
      },
      {
        "text":"b2 text i2",
       "type" : "b1",
       },
      {
        "text":"c1 text i.",
         "type" : "c1",
       },
        {
           "text":"c2 text i2",
          "type" : "c1",
        },
     ]
      }
      })
  })
```

get the items in tab which matches the type

Comment: https://codepen.io/aish-29/pen/jXQLJK?editors=1111

Comment: here's my pen what i have accomplised so far